# Using variable in different class

Tags: java, eclipse

Using a variable from another class won't work. 
I'm trying to send and use **mx** and **my** from MouseListener() from *class graphics* here

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class graphics {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setSize(640,480);
  frame.setTitle("graphics");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  
  drawingComponents dc = new drawingComponents();
  frame.add(dc);

  frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         double mx = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
         double my = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
         System.out.println("Mouse x " + mx + " y " + my); 
     };
  });  
 }
}
```

to *class drawingComponents* here and use it to draw at the position of the mouse.

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class drawingComponents extends JComponent{

 public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           graphics g3 = new graphics();
    System.out.println(g3.mx, g3.my);
 } 
}
```

I can get the **mx** and **my** in *class graphics* but using it in *class drawingComponents* will tell me `mx/my cannot be resolved or is not a field`. In *class drawingComponents*, Declaring it as

```js
double mx;
double my;
```

will not change anything.

Comment: This looks like Java **not** Javascript - they are completely different programming languages.

Comment: my bad @greg-449

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are local, not only are they not accessible by other classes but they are not accessible by external methods in your graphics class. You should pass them as arguments when you create your drawingComponents class. If you do not like this, you can set up a method in drawingComponents to add them later. You can also make the variables class variables for graphics and then have a getter method for other classes to get them. Finally (and this is not recommended as it is bad practice) you can make the variables public and static.

Good luck.